# Why does adding an empty for loop fix this code?

Tags: java, android, ringtone

I am trying to play a ringtone selected by the user.

When I use this code:

```
RingtoneManager ringtoneManager = new RingtoneManager(this);
Uri uri = ringtoneManager.getRingtoneUri(position);

if(uri == null) {
    Log.d("ALARM", "uri is null");
}

try {
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();  
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mediaPlayer.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle exception
}
```

I get "uri is null" and nothing happens, however if I put in an empty for loop beforehand like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ringtoneManager.getCursor().getCount(); ++i) {
//WTF
}

RingtoneManager ringtoneManager = new RingtoneManager(this);
Uri uri = ringtoneManager.getRingtoneUri(position);

if(uri == null) {
    Log.d("ALARM", "uri is null");
}

try {
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();  
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mediaPlayer.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle exception
}
```

The uri is not null and the ringtone plays...

Can anyone explain what is going on here, and what I am supposed to do to avoid this hack?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tested if just waiting for as long as the for loop takes, just calling `ringtoneManager.getCursor().getCount()` or just calling `ringtoneManager.getCursor()` also fixes your problem? If yes to any of the above, that'll help narrow things down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RingtoneManager` [has two constructors](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html#RingtoneManager%28android.content.Context%29). One of them takes in a Context and the other takes an Activity. According to the docs, the one that takes an Activity will manage the cursor for you. The one that takes a Context will not.

If the docs are to be believed, sounds like your `this` is not an Activity, and thus, the `RingtoneManager` instance you are getting is not managing the cursor and is expecting you to call `getCursor()`.